# WSDL soap with php returns a mix of object and arrays?

Tags: wsdl, webservice-client

I am having some problems with a WSDL service, if i use php's built in soap class to create a $client and __call function.

The output is a mix of objects and arrays like

```
[AvailableRatePlans] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [RatePlanAvail] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
```

When i use the "old" nusoap.php i just get arrays back.

What do i do wrong? Any tips, suggestions?

regards

Comment: hmm, not pretty, but at the moment i converted the last object i have to parse by using objectToArray http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/

Answer (score 0):

PHP will convert response to object of stdClass and there is nothing wrong with it. It's just way of dealing with response XML.

You are not doing anything wrong but it's just SOAP extensions way of dealing with ComplexType webservice depending on WSDL structure.

To make it easy you can simply cast it with array and it should be as good as old way while you were using nusoap lib.

```
$Response = (array)$Response;
```

stdClass objects will be converted to associative array w/o any problem.